# There are infinite white dot when I pack up Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I input the command `ionic cordova build android`,but it became infinite white dots eventually .
[image: infinite white dots]

my environment as belows

[image]

What should I do next?

Comment: could you print here your `ionic info`  here

Comment: @Eve check my answer if confusion then ask me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its infinite white dots showing download gradle file for android..**

If you use `ionic cordova build android` or `ionic cordova run android` for first time its download its associated .gradle file and this process showing white dot.

Comment: I'm so sorry.I'm so busy today.I'm gonna tell you result.thx a lot.

Comment: it was really downloading gradle file.But it `build android` failed eventually.My project is new with command `ionic start ev2 tabs`.I don't change anything.I'm gonna show the error in next comment.

Comment: BUILD FAILED in 32s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (F:\ev2\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)

Comment: (node:16248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: (node:16248) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Its your download gradle problem.First of all what you ask me i solve this so its second question. so delete all gradle file from .gradle folder and also delete platform and plugin and node_modules and start command npm install and then ionic cordova prepare --save